# Retrieving everything after ? in a query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am actually an HW and FW engineer and very new to web programming.

In a recent product we embedded wi-fi connectivity and our products(clients) send get requests to a server using the format below and it is unfortunately fixed.

```
IP Number:Port Number/default.aspx?XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XXY*Z*
```

- *XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX* is the MAC address of the product
- *Y* is an integer which may vary between 1 to 99999
- *Z* is the opcode which may again vary from A to Z

We want to get everything after the `?` sign to determine from which terminal this request is coming from and which action we shall take in the database.

Since we are using IIS webserver we think an asp page fits better to such a requirement.

What method would you request to retrieve all the string after the `?` sign using C#.

Comment: could you please post a valid string as code? does it have line breaks in it?

Comment: I guess the line breaks were just from a copy+paste.

Comment: @TKZ have you tried anything so far? You say about IIS and asp.net, but have you already started a website?

Comment: if you have it as a string get the index and take the substring from there on:`string info = urlString.Substring(urlString.IndexOf('?'))`

Comment: Yes I have a web page running on IIS doing nothing other than printing Hello Wolrd to the browser.

Comment: Request.QueryString.ToString(); worked for me very well.Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Request.Url.Query` if you want the raw query string as a string.

I usually use `Request.Url.ToString()` to get the full URL (including query string), no concatenation required.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the Urls using the [Uri class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.0)

```
var queryPart = new Uri("your url here").Query;
```